# AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext can't access token value in Owin.Security / Identity Framework upon token refresh

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, katana, refresh-token

In a .net project with Identity Framework I can't renew tokens, even though I can generate one. The exception is follows:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: token]
 Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext..ctor(IOwinContext context, ISecureDataFormat`1 secureDataFormat, String token) +136
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeTokenEndpointRefreshTokenGrantAsync>d__44.MoveNext() +158
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__1e.MoveNext() +2159
```

Due to this exception, the debugger won't even step into the token refreshing function:

```
 public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {

            var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

            string hashedTokenId = Helper.GetHash(context.Token);

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var refreshToken = await _repo.FindRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);

                if (refreshToken != null )
                {
                    //Get protectedTicket from refreshToken class
                    context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
                    var result = await _repo.RemoveRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm debugging using Postman, and the request posted contain proper token, which isn't detected in request body, neither in request header.

Katana dev team has marked this as a bug: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/480 but also stated that no updates are coming.

The same codebase runs on a remote server: http://ngauthenticationweb.azurewebsites.net/

Complete project in which this can be reproduced is available at: https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication

How could I force token into the context, to prevent the exception?

Comment: I know this is a long shot, but did you ever fix this? Do you remember what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the grant_type and client_id in postman? The grant_type should be 'password'.

Sample:
username=abcd&password=abc@123&grant_type=password&client_id=c4b2f91dbe014b558d7fa00ca54ed33d

Comment: grant_type is 'password' on initial login and it works great. What doesn't work is grant_type of 'refresh_token' - which is used for refresh token based reauthentication.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the authorization header in postman, so the systems knows the user is authorized to refresh the token.

Example:

[image: example]